# XSLT output is under header parent where ns1:response is required

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I have written a XSLT mapping to remove the duplicates and it is not working as expected.

Sample incoming XML -

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
  <OrganizationMaster>
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001607</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>ENGINEERING DEPT</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
  <OrganizationMaster>
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001605</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>F&amp;A</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
</ns1:Response>
```

XSLT - mapping to perform group-by on "OrganizationDepartmentID"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="OrganizationMaster" 
                group-by="OrganizationDepartmentID">                
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>               
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ns1:Response>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output - namespace is copied in every child node under "Response"

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
  <OrganizationMaster xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001607</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>ENGINEERING DEPT</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
  <OrganizationMaster xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001605</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>F&amp;A</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
</ns1:Response>
```

**Required Output -**

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:OrgMasterData_Portal">
  <OrganizationMaster>
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001607</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>ENGINEERING DEPT</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
  <OrganizationMaster>
    <OrganizationCompanyID>504</OrganizationCompanyID>
    <OrganizationCompanyName>UNITED FUEL COMPANY LIMITED</OrganizationCompanyName>
    <LegacyCompanyID>3857</LegacyCompanyID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentID>10001605</OrganizationDepartmentID>
    <OrganizationDepartmentName>F&amp;A</OrganizationDepartmentName>
    <LegacyDepartmentID/>
    <CountryName>Saudi Arabia</CountryName>
  </OrganizationMaster>
</ns1:Response>
```

Can someone please help me fix the XSLT code.

Comment: THe current output and the required output are 100% equivalent. Mentioning the namespace more often than necessary is not a actual issue. It's purely a cosmetic detail, it won't have any effect on how the result XML works.

Comment: It depends on your XSLT processor - Saxon 9.8 HE seems to produce the lower output right from the start: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAh